# Magento2.2 product import using Magmi

Tags: magento2.2, magento-2.2.5, import-products, product-import

Is Magmi import is compatible with Magento2.2? Is it compatible with grouped and simple products import? Where I can find the Latest version of Magmi?

Answer (score 1):

Is Magmi import is compatible with Magento2.2? -> **Yes**

Is it compatible with grouped and simple products import? -> **Yes**

Where I can find the Latest version of Magmi? -> https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2

Comment: I'm getting two issues with grouped products:

1. The simple products are not visible on the grouped product until we save the grouped product from the admin.

2. While importing the category, we are getting the below error message:
"SKU TEST - 2 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_name.ccev.value' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by - ERROR ON RECORD #3"

Comment: I don't want to make any changes in the database setting for the 2nd issue.

Below is the "categories" coloumn value:
[Root Category]/Parent Category/Child Category

Comment: Do you have any idea how to resolve these issues?

Do you have a sample CSV file for the grouped product import for Magmi?

Comment: read this https://www.webguys.de/magento-1/turchen-19-produktimport-mit-der-importexport-schnittstelle

Answer (score 0):

please check below link for M2:

```
https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2
```